# WordPress Fishpig get select type value associated for each post

Tags: magento-1.9, wordpress

I need to get the selected post type of a post in wordpress.

I am using Fishpig module, so wp default way of getting the article type wont work.

I am following this:
https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/code-examples/

But not able to get the post type.

Im trying by this:

UPDATED:

If i try with this below line, i get custom fields values

```
addMetaFieldToFilter('type', array('Articles','Artists & Makers','Videos'))
```

But if i use it with $collection, i wont get other details related to posts like post author, post title etc

```
<?php $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/post_collection')
    ->setOrderByPostDate()
    ->addIsViewableFilter()
    ->addPostTypeFilter(array('post')) // Add any post types here
    ->setPageSize(9) // Limits to 9 posts. Remove from all posts
    ->load();
?>
    <?php if (count($collection) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($collection as $post):
            echo '<pre>';echo 'POSTS---';   print_r($post)
            ?>

            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>"><?php echo $post->getPostTitle() ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Output:**

> POSTS---Fishpig_Wordpress_Model_Post Object ( [_metaTable:protected] => wordpress/post_meta [_metaTableObjectField:protected] => post_id [_eventPrefix:protected] => wordpress_post [_eventObject:protected] => post [_metaHasPrefix:protected] => [_meta:protected] => Array ( )[_metaKeysChanged:protected] => Array ( )[_resourceName:protected] => wordpress/post [_resource:protected] => [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => wordpress/post_collection [_cacheTag:protected] => [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1 [_isObjectNew:protected] => [_data:protected] => Array ( [ID] => 110258 [post_author] => 2 [post_date] => 2017-10-23 11:21:27 [post_date_gmt] => 2017-10-23 11:21:27 [post_content] =>

But if print_r the $collection , i dont get the post_type value like i have in the drop down 'articles'

There seems to no post type in this

These are my custom fields of type select with different values.

[image]

And i need to get the selected type value for each post (In this case the type selected is 'article')

[image]

Comment: What's `echo $collection->getSelect();` giving you?

Comment: Have posted the output for getSelect() @RickyOdinMatthews

Comment: try replace `addFieldToFilter` with `addTaxonomyFilter('*')`

Comment: not working..getting error

Comment: Also im trying with ths: ->addMetaFieldToFilter('type', 1)   can u please tell what should be used in place of 'type', from this reference link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603961/how-to-get-post-collection-in-magento-by-fishpig-wordpress-extension-4-0  @RickyOdinMatthews

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/post_collection')
    ->setOrderByPostDate()
    ->addIsViewableFilter()
    ->addPostTypeFilter(array('post')) // Add any post types here
    ->setPageSize(9) // Limits to 9 posts. Remove from all posts
    ->load() ?>
<?php if (count($collection) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($collection as $post): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>"><?php echo $post->getPostTitle() ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I need to get the custom fields - type (drop down choices )value for each of the post , have updated the question with what you have posted, im stuck as to why im not getting the choices value @Ben Tideswell

Comment: Can you please suggest to get my requirement something like u have mentioned here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791577/how-to-filter-by-custom-field-in-fishpig

Comment: Hey @Ben Tideswell, could you please suggest on this?

Comment: I have done. Stop posting in this question to ask for replies to another question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this but not sure

```
<?php $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/post_collection')
    ->setOrderByPostDate()
    ->addFieldToFilter('*')
    ->addIsViewableFilter()
    ->addPostTypeFilter('post')
    ->setPageSize(9); 
?>
```

Comment: No i get sql error

Comment: please post the error.

Comment: have posted the error @MR.R Dhath

Comment: Syntax error or access violation, check your query ....May be semicolon.
I have made this mistake during post.
Please check current update code.

Comment: I noticed that semicolon in your previous post, but i have corrected it in my code and its currently the same as u have posted and also have posted the output for $collection->getSelect() query

Comment: wordpress/post    -- Alias  table name check...
Please check all field name , it will be declare in sql folder of your module.
This field name which you want , must be declare in sql query.
IF not , you have to  make some join .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78241/discussion-between-mr-r-dnath-and-sushivam).

Comment: i cant see u in chat @MR.R Dhath